# I have changed the Template for the radiobutton. but the groupname property doesnot work

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I have created a controltemplate for my radiobutton. The groupName property doesn't seem to work. My both radio buttons gets checked. Also binding happens only during the load time and after that the properties also donot get updated. Am I missing something here?
Please find the xaml code and the resource file code below:

XAML code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IntegerToBooleanConverter x:Key="IntegerToBooleanConverter"/>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApplication;component/Styles/RadioButtonShadowEffect.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Name="Header" Content="Get from resource file" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="15,15,15,0" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Separator Margin="15,15,15,0"/>
        <Label Name="ContentTitle" Content="Get from resource file" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="30,15,15,0"/>
        <Grid Margin="35,15,15,0" Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <RadioButton Template="{StaticResource MultiLineRadioButtonTemplate}" Name="RadioSingleBore" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  IsChecked="{Binding BoreCount, Mode=TwoWay, Converter ={StaticResource IntegerToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter= 1}" GroupName="BoreCount">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Border Name="RadioSingleBoreBorder" Background="LightGray" Margin="0,15,0,0" Height="300" Width="290" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Label Name="RadioSingleBoreLabel" Content="Get from rosource file" Margin="15"/>
                                    <Image Name="SingleBoreImage" Stretch="Fill" Height="40" Margin="17,70,17,15" Source="SomeImage"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                </RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <RadioButton Template="{StaticResource MultiLineRadioButtonTemplate}" Name="RadioDoubleBore"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding BoreCount, Mode=TwoWay, Converter ={StaticResource IntegerToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter= 2}"  GroupName="BoreCount">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border Name="RadioDoubleBoreBorder" Background="LightGray" Margin="0,15,0,0" Height="300" Width="290" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Label Name="RadioDoubleBoreLabel" Content="Get from rosource file" Margin="15"/>
                            <Image Name="DoubleBoreImage" Stretch="Fill" Height="110" Margin="17,35,17,15" Source="SomeImage"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The resoucre file is as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MultiLineRadioButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}">
        <TextBlock>
        <LineBreak />
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <ContentPresenter Margin="-15,0,0,0" 
                              Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate}"/>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        </TextBlock>
    </RadioButton>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My converter code is as follows:

```
public class IntegerToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int source = 1;
        int target = 1;

        int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out source);
        int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out target);

        return (source == target);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ControlTemplate` for `RadioButton` has another `RadioButton` in it. I guess, your group name is not getting inherited by the nested `RadioButton` defined within the Template.

Update your ControlTemplate to:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MultiLineRadioButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" GroupName="{TemplateBinding GroupName}">
        <TextBlock>
            <LineBreak />
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <ContentPresenter Margin="-15,0,0,0" 
                      Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate}"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </TextBlock>
    </RadioButton>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Basically, this ControlTemplate sets GroupName property on the RadioButton via a `TemplateBinding`.

I have tested this code and seem to work fine.

Comment: Thanks!!! That works...Can you please tell me why my binding doesn't doesn't work...On load my Converter is called, but binding doesn't work some how

Comment: In your template you only set `IsChecked` via TemplateBinding, but not `GroupName`. That means, both nested `RadioButton`s have blank/empty `GroupName`. WPF thinks, those two RadioButtons doesn't belong to same group, since they both have empty `GroupName` - hence the behaviour you saw. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I understood the groupName thing...but I am not able to find out why the radio buttons are not being binded to the property although on load the value converter return the values as expected

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say binding doesn't work, is your IsChecked property not updated in the ViewModel?

Comment: Yes my IsChecked property is not getting updated in the viewModel. Also onload the first button should have been checked, that also doesn't happen even though the convert method was called. When I check the radion button the convertback method is not even called.

Comment: Regarding the `IsChecked` property not being updated in the ViewModel, I think, there is known issue with `RadioButton`. Please refer to this [post](http://wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html). I will have to look at your Converter to comment on the other two questions.

Comment: Hmm.. that looks tricky. Not sure, if we can ConverterParamter to the nested RadioButton in the Template. Will try more on this and follow this thread to see if someone else posts the answer.

Comment: @RaviDugar I am on a holiday with no access to Visual Studio, I will be back only in the new year. So, I am afraid I can't help.